# How is the at sign (@) used in the c source code for numpy?

Tags: python, c, numpy, macros

I've been perusing some of the source code for numpy and I noticed that a lot of the c source code uses the construction `@variablename@`.  For example, in the file "npy_math_complex.c.src" (located [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_complex.c.src)):

```
/*==========================================================
* Constants
*=========================================================*/
static const @ctype@ c_1@c@ = {1.0@C@, 0.0};
static const @ctype@ c_half@c@ = {0.5@C@, 0.0};
static const @ctype@ c_i@c@ = {0.0, 1.0@C@};
static const @ctype@ c_ihalf@c@ = {0.0, 0.5@C@};
```

What do `@ctype@` and `@c@` mean? Are these some sort of macros? I'm guessing they aren't normal C-macros since I've looked at the relevant header files listed in the file and they don't appear to define any macros using "@".

Is `@name@` some sort of macro used by `distutils` when compiling c code into a python module?

I've never seen an `@` sign used in c code before and so I'm a bit confused...

Comment: It's used by some sort of template engine to generate multiple very similar functions with the `@`-marked parts substituted, but I've never figured out what template system they're using or the precise details of what code is generated.

Comment: Note that the filename `npy_math_complex.c.src` is a clue....

Comment: The numpy docs give a very brief overview here: https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/distutils_guide.html#other-files

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because these files are templates. If I remember correctly NumPy uses several template engines (thanks @user2357112 for helping me finding the appropriate one):

- [tempita (for Cython files)](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.13.1/tools/cythonize.py)
- [another one for C files](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.13.1/numpy/distutils/conv_template.py)
- [another one for FORTRAN files](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.13.1/numpy/distutils/from_template.py)

and the second one is actually responsible to convert these to "regular" C files - before these get compiled.

Basically these functions will be cloned a lot of times and for each of the functions a special placeholder is inserted between the `%`.

For example [in this case it begins with](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.13.1/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_complex.c.src#L45-L55):

```
/**begin repeat
 * #type = npy_float, npy_double, npy_longdouble#
 * #ctype = npy_cfloat,npy_cdouble,npy_clongdouble#
 * #c = f, , l#
 * #C = F, , L#
 * ....
 */
```

So in the first iteration `@ctype@` will be replaced with `npy_cfloat` and `@c@` with `f` and `@C@` with `F`:

```c
static const npy_cfloat c_1f = {1.0F, 0.0};
static const npy_cfloat c_halff = {0.5F, 0.0};
static const npy_cfloat c_if = {0.0, 1.0F};
static const npy_cfloat c_ihalff = {0.0, 0.5F};
```

In the next iteration is `@ctype@` `npy_cdouble`, ...

```c
static const npy_cdouble c_1 = {1.0, 0.0};
static const npy_cdouble c_half = {0.5, 0.0};
static const npy_cdouble c_i = {0.0, 1.0};
static const npy_cdouble c_ihalf = {0.0, 0.5};
```

and in the third iteration:

```c
static const npy_clongdouble c_1l = {1.0L, 0.0};
static const npy_clongdouble c_halfl = {0.5L, 0.0};
static const npy_clongdouble c_il = {0.0, 1.0L};
static const npy_clongdouble c_ihalfl = {0.0, 0.5L};
```

these are then compiled as normal C files.

Comment: I took a quick look through the source for the tempita usage, but it seems to only be used to generate Cython files, not C. Also, the syntax doesn't seem to match tempita. The C templates appear to be handled differently.

Comment: @user2357112 Ah, that could be. I found another document that explicitly mentions the `.xxx.src` -> `.xxx` conversion: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/a5d71d64a0d2e7a50562df80349219080172f254/numpy/distutils/from_template.py But it's really hard to find out if that's really what is used there. But I'm sure about one thing: They use a template engine :D

Comment: No, I think that's yet another template engine. The `.c.src` files seem to be handled by the similarly-named [`numpy/distutils/conv_template.py`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/b5cc18d1e45f39fe98a743b3b41b99c70681e51c/numpy/distutils/conv_template.py).

Comment: (There are way more template engines in this project than I expected.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! For some reason I was thinking that disutils was doing the replacement... so you've saved me a great deal of time...